# MongoDB - aggregation to pull unique documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and my document looks like this:

```
_id:5e58f340862df1a7b4e62b35
Date:1996-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
abd: 22
bvh: 21
ThingID:166
ThingValue:1
```

```
_id:5e58hf4862df1a7b4e62b35
Date:2000-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
abd: 22
bvh: 21
ThingID:166
ThingValue:1
```

These 2 represent the same thing but one is for 1996 and the other for 2000 - what is the best way for me to:

`SELECT (ThingID, ThingValue) where abd = abd, bvh = bvh AND Date is latest`

I have tried this:

```py
mongo.db[collection].find({'$and': [{'abd': {'$eq': abd}},{'bvh': {'$eq': bvh}}]},
                             {"ThingID": 1,"ThingValue": 1, "_id": 0})
                    .sort([("Date", -1)])
                    .distinct('ThingID'))
```

This works if they were only ever 1 ThingID which I would want to return - However, there could be any number of distinct ThingID that satisfies this logic and I would have to return all of them..

I.E:

```
_id:5e58cd90862df1a7b4e62b35
Date:1996-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
abd: 22
bvh: 21
ThingID:166
ThingValue:1
```

```
_id:5e58cd67562df1a7b4e62b35
Date:2000-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
abd: 22
bvh: 21
ThingID:166
ThingValue:1
```

```
_id:5e76cd90862df1a7b4e62b35
Date:2000-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00
abd: 22
bvh: 21
ThingID:167
ThingValue:1
```

I would need to return the documents (5e58cd90862df1a7b4e62b35, e58cd90862df1a7b4e62b35) as that is the latest that have unique ThingIDs but also satisfies the lookup logic

I need some sort of aggregation (I think)

Comment: Please check my answer !! But I've a question if you only need `ThingID` & `ThingValue` in output, then why do you need to sort it on `Date` field (why latest one) ?? - it will be helpful if you're filtering on date less-than or greater than a given date in input but we're not doing that then I think getting doc by latest date is not needed for your requirement !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** match docs on criteria to lessesn dataset size */
    {
        $match: {
            abd: 22,
            bvh: 21
        }
    },
    /** sort on Date field to get latest docs up on all documents left after match stage */
    {
        $sort: {
            Date: -1
        }
    },
    /** group on ThingID & push first found document to field named data */
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ThingID",
            data: {
                $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    /** So make data field as root, So data field will be new document */
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$data"
        }
    },
    /** Project field only what we need, By default _id will be present so we need to pass _id: 0 to ignore it */
    {
        $project: {
            ThingID: 1,
            ThingValue: 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wuIjo-cqajr)

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to help you as all documents have the same `_id` (which is not possible in reality). Anyway, I assume you are looking for this:

```
db.collection.find(
   { abd: 22, bvh: 21 },
   {
      ThingID: 1,
      ThingValue: 1,
      _id: 0
   }
).sort({ Date: -1 }).limit(1)
```

Note, `{ abd: 22, bvh: 21 }` is equal to `{ '$and': [{ 'abd': { '$eq': 22 } }, { 'bvh': { '$eq': 21 } }] }` - but I am a lazy guy.

In order to get all documents of most recent date, use this aggregation pipeline. However, I don't know what you actually like to get from those records.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { abd: 22, bvh: 21 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$Date",
         data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
   { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Comment: I seem to get: `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Comment: Provide valid example documents, then you may get help. Or you did a simple typo.

Comment: The answer is just what I provided without `.distinct()` right? - the issue is, with `limit()` is set to 1, what happens when there are 2 values that satisfy the conditions

Comment: with `.distinct()` that works but I lose the `ThingValue` col

Comment: You get only the first one. If you want to change, you have to write an aggregation pipeline

Comment: Yes. In my Q I say `I need some sort of aggregation (I think)` - is there any chance you could help with writing an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Ok cool so that edit returns the whole document, how would I just return 2 specific entries in the document, i.e:  `ThingID` and `ThingValue`

Comment: Try it by yourself, I am not your ghostwriter - or ask a new question if you get stuck.